# How can I open pdf in separate tab or download the pdf without affecting the app in mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, anchor

I have one button where users can click and download certain pdf files. On a desktop, it works perfectly. But when I try to download the pdf, it just replaces the main app and opens the pdf in the same tab. However, if the block popover is disabled then it opens in the new tab. But by default and in most cases it is enabled.

Is there any solution, where the pdf will be opened in the new tab although block popover is activated?

I am using TypeScript with nextjs. Thank you very much for your help.

1. I tried to use `window.open("pdf_file_link", "_blank)`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
window.open("pdf_file_link")
```